# Auto Increment in update statement resulting in duplicate values on large table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I had a need to renumber rows in a table using the following code from a [You've Been Haacked blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2004/02/28/sql-auto-increment.aspx/):

```
DECLARE @counter int
SET @counter = 0
UPDATE #myTable
SET @counter = ID = @counter + 1
```

This works fine with a few records to several thousand, but when I run it on a SQL Server 2012 (64-bit) instance on a table with 250K+ records, I end up with many duplicates (ID #1 appears 12 times). In all, there are about 27K records with duplicate values. The strange thing is that about 19K have exactly 12 dupes (the same number of processors on my machine).

What is the cause of the duplicates?

Comment: I'd say that this statement gets executed in parallel, not line by line. And therefore the counter doesn't get incremented "quick enough".,

Comment: Can you post your query plan?

Comment: This is not the best way to do this. ROW_NUMBER would be a much better approach as @GiorgiNakeuri already said. You could add the query hint OPTION (MAXDOP 1) to prevent it from spilling onto more than 1 processor. The performance however is likely to suffer.

Comment: Welcome to 2015. Use a sequence or identity column instead of calculating it yourself.

Comment: @C-PoundGuru If you're trying to implement yourself this because of performance kimberly tripp has allot of great info on the subject http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/category/primary-keys/

Comment: This is affectionately called a "quirky update" - don't use it. The syntax is undocumented, unsupported, and does not protect you from collisions due to concurrency / parallelism.

Comment: I appreciate the comments on this--it was driving me nuts.  This code is a holdover from when we had to support SQL Server 2000 which didn't have the ROW_NUMBER option.  I've already changed it to use a Common Table Expression using ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Your comment would be more constructive without the "Welcome to...". I would use an Identity column if my numbering always started at the same number. Instead, it starts at a number based on existing data.  Since you can't use a variable to declare an Identity column seed, I would have to use a string to build the sql--I didn't want to do that. This method worked fine (up til now).

Comment: @C-PoundGuru: Sorry if you got offended by my comment. I still stand by my suggestion. there are good ways and bad ways to do things, re-inventing the sequence is probably in the second category. If the variable as seed is the problem, you might want to consider declaring it using dynamic sql.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not guaranteed to work which I'm sure Phil Haack calls out. Throw this code away.

The likely reason is parallelism. That variable might be hammered on multiple threads.

> The strange thing is that about 19K have exactly 12 dupes (the same number of processors on my machine).

That fits the explanation.

Use `ROW_NUMBER` to generate good guaranteed to work IDs:

```
update t
set ID = r
from (
 select *, row_number() over (order by something) r from T
) t
```

Just as simple but sane.